# Querying the Subfields in cloudant:

Tags: subquery, ibm-cloud, cloudant, nosql

My database contains docs with the below structure:

```
{
  "_id": "xx",
  "_rev": "xx",
  "metadata": [
    {
      "name": "par1",
      "value": "val1"
    },
    {
      "name": "par2",
      "value": "val2"
    },
    {
      "name": "par3",
      "value": "val3"
    },
    {
      "name": "par4",
      "value": "val4"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to run queries somethings like:

```
{
  "selector": 
  {
    "metadata.name":"par1"
   }
 }
```

but currently my above selector doesn't work.
I have created a text type index for all the fields. basically I want to do the queried on sub-fields where sub-field itself is an object containing 2 data members "name" and "value". Any help or leads will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using java cloudant api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector cannot access `metadata.name` directly because `metadata` is an array.  A couple of options which may satisfy your goal:

1) If you've created a full text index for all fields and you want to search for "par1" in any field, then your selector like the one below should work.  The caveat is that it returns docs where "par1" is any index field:

```
{
  "selector":
  {
    "$text": "par1"
  }
}
```

2) If you want to search specifically on documents where a metadata[i].name field contains "par1", then you can create a view for docs keyed on the metadata[i].name value where the map function looks something like:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.metadata) {
    for (i = 0; i < doc.metadata.length; i++) {
      emit(doc.metadata[i].name, doc._id);
    }
  }
}
```

You can then get all docs where 'name' is 'par1' with the following (replacing all values in curly braces with your specific identifiers):

```
curl -s https://{userid}:{password}@{userid}.cloudant.com/{db_name}/_design/{design_doc_name}/_view/{view_name}?key=%22par1%22&include_docs=true
```